# Cannot convert seq of parameterized types to a map

Tags: scala

Why does the following code:

```
case class Test[E](name: String, e: E)
val seq = Seq[Test[_]]()
val map = seq.map(i => i.name -> i).toMap
```

Give me this compiler error:

> Cannot prove that (String, Test[_$1]) forSome { type _$1 } <:< (T, U)

Comment: Interestingly, if `seq` is defined, say, `val seq = Seq[Test[Int]]()` things do compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two options are:

```
case class Test[E](name: String, e: E)

val seq = Seq[Test[_]]()
val map = seq.map(i => i.name -> i).toMap[String, Test[_]]
```

Or you can also "inform" the compiler about the map type ahead of time which also works.

```
val seq = Seq.empty[Test[_]]
val map: Map[String, Test[_]] = seq.map(i => i.name -> i).toMap
```

**Why this doesn't work**

As to why this doesn't work, it really should, but what happens is Scala uses an implicit to determine the inner type of a collection `M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]` is a tuple, and that's found in the `toMap` signature.

```
 def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U]
```

The part you care about is `A <:< (T, U)`, which is saying `A` is actually a subtype of `Tuple2[T, U]` where `T` should become the keytype and `U` the value type. `A` is the original underlying type of the collection.

Somehow the compiler is not smart enough to infer `(T, U)` unless you explicitly provided, and it seems it doesn't have anything to do with the existential type either.

In theory you should be able to convert any traversable to a map easily, and we can reconstruct what happens when you call `toMap` using higher kinds.

```
implicit class TraversableOps[
  // We are saying here every M is a higher kinded collection type
  // that extends TraversableOnce, like Map, Seq, and so on.
  M[A] <: TraversableOnce[A],
  T
](val col: M[T]) {
  // Proof that T is actually a tuple2 type.
  def customToMap[K, V](implicit ev: T <:< (K, V)): Map[K, V] = {
   ...
  }
}
```